# Golang Go-SQLite3 cannot iterate over type error

Tags: go, sqlite

When attempting to use the examples from github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3's repository, I get the following error when trying to compile the code with Go 1.5.1 darwin/amd64:

```
non-bool rows.Next() (type error) used as for condition
```

The code I'm using is:

```
conn, err := sqlite3.Open("./example.db")
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
defer conn.Close()
rows, err := conn.Query("SELECT * FROM scans ORDER BY id DESC;")
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
for rows.Next() {
    var id int
    var method string
    var uuid string
    var scan int
    rows.Scan(&id, &method, &uuid, &scan)
    log.Print(id, method, uuid, scan)
}
```

Is there something which I am missing here? This is based on the example found here:
https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/master/_example/simple/simple.go#L81-L91

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are missing.

You are not using the [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) package but you are using the [`sqlite3`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-sqlite/go1/sqlite3) package!

---

[`sql.Open()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open) returns an [`sql.DB`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB), [`DB.Query()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) returns an [`sql.Rows`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows), and [`Rows.Next()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Next) is:

```
func (rs *Rows) Next() bool
```

But instead you call [`sqlite3.Open()`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-sqlite/go1/sqlite3#Open) which returns an [`sqlite3.Conn`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-sqlite/go1/sqlite3#Conn), then you call [`Conn.Query()`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-sqlite/go1/sqlite3#Conn.Query) which returns an [`sqlite3.Stmt`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-sqlite/go1/sqlite3#Stmt) which you name **`rows`**! So **`rows.Next()`** is **[`Stmt.Next()`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-sqlite/go1/sqlite3#Stmt.Next)** which is:

```
func (s *Stmt) Next() error
```

---

#### Source of confusion

It is confusing because sqlite3 is a driver conforming to the built-in `database/sql` interface, but it also provides another interface and you used it via its vendor-specific sqlite3 interface.

Using the `database/sql` package you would start it like this:

```
db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./foo.db")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't figure this out for the life of me and this makes much more sense and as soon as I switched to this things worked as expected. I really appreciate the help